# Neo4j 2.1+ - Cypher - Return number of times a relationship appears when using DISTINCT

Tags: count, neo4j, distinct, cypher, relationships

I'm struggling with maybe a simple query but I'm unable to find an answer :

Let's give the following simple schema :

**Nodes :**

```
Package1
Library1
Library2
Library3
```

**Relationships:**

```
(Library1)-[:USES {in_version:'1.1'}]->(Package1)
(Library2)-[:USES {in_version:'1.2'}]->(Package1)
(Library3)-[:USES {in_version:'1.2'}]->(Package1)
```

Simple no ?

So what I would like is to return my package node, and group relationships by distinct in_version property and the number of times the in_version is used

This should be the return I would like to have :

```
package    |  in_version  |  usage  |
Package 1  |  1.1         |  1      |
Package 1  |  1.2         |  2      |
```

I tried to combine distinct, collect, ..but I'm struggling currently

**Edit**

My last query is as follow :

```
MATCH (p:Package)<-[r:USES]-()
WHERE p.name = 'Package1'
WITH p, collect(r) as v
UNWIND v as x
RETURN distinct x.in_version, count(x) as usage
ORDER BY usage DESC
```

And I can get the versions and the usage correctly.
But if I want to add the package name to the return, cypher complain about the '.' in x.in_version

```
MATCH (p:Package)<-[r:USES]-()
WHERE p.name = 'Package1'
WITH p, collect(r) as v
UNWIND v as x
RETURN p.name, distinct x.in_version, count(x) as usage
ORDER BY usage DESC
```

While the p.name is not necessary for this query as I know it in advance, the goal is to 1st filter packages having the most uses relations and then return this query by package in one time

Thanks in advance

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
match (lib)-[r:USES]->(pack)
where has(r.in_version)
with pack, collect(r.in_version) as vers,lib
with pack,vers ,collect(lib) as libs,count(lib) as usage
return pack as package,vers as in_version,usage
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have now the package name but the usage is always returning 1.

Comment: can you create a graph gist and share it??